# Dynamics NAV 2017 .NET interop: exception occurred, 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=5.0.0.0

Tags: c#, dll, microsoft-dynamics

I built a C# library to pull an API that generates a QR code. I want to use it in Microsoft Dynamic Navision to put QRCodes on invoices etc. I have never built anything for Dynamics Navision before but have read and followed along with Microsoft documents for the bing maps for a guide.

When I load the dll in the control add-in page, all works fine. When I go into object designer to make a global variable and select the dll, I get the following error message popup that talks about System.Runtime not being found. The only thing I can think of is that perhaps Microsoft.Drawing.Common links back to a previous version? Has anyone had the luck of solving this error?

Almost everything I have come across on StackOverflow so far has been to find the error inside Visual Studio, which is NOT where I am getting the issue. Thanks in advance for any help!

Platform target in VS2019 is set to **Any CPU**

Application is built for **.NET 5.0** and the target framework is set to the same

The project is set as a class library

**Error Message**

[image: Error Message]

**Nav Control Add in page**

[image: Control Add In Page]

**Sample Code**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using Microsoft.Dynamics.Framework.UI.Extensibility;

namespace Navrae.ZebraApi.AddIn
{
    [ControlAddInExport("Navrae.2DQRCode.AddIn")]
    public static class BuildApi
    {
        [ApplicationVisible]
        public static Uri BuildUri(string symbology, string text)
        {
            UriBuilder uri = new UriBuilder("https://api.zebra.com/v2/tools/barcode/generate");
            uri.Query = $"?symbology={symbology}&text={text}";
            return uri.Uri;
        }
        
        [ApplicationVisible]
        public static void GetQrCodeFromZebraApi(string uri, string zebraApiKey)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(uri);
            webRequest.ContentType = "image/png";
            webRequest.Method = "GET";
            webRequest.Headers.Add("apikey", zebraApiKey);

            using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse) webRequest.GetResponse())
            {
                
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = reader.ReadBytes((int) response.ContentLength);
                    ConvertBytesToImage(bytes);
                }
            }
        }

        private static void ConvertBytesToImage(byte[] bytes)
        {
            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))
                {
                    do magical conversion
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw new NullReferenceException(e.Message);
            }
        }

        private static void SaveImage(Image newImage)
        {
            save image
        }

    }
}
```

And here are my properties on the DLL file:

[image: ReadWriteProp]

[image: Version etc.]

Comment: You can't target .NET5, use the "Class Library (.NET Framework)" project template to get started.

Comment: Thanks I’ll give it a go!

Comment: @HansPassant I appreciate it! The dll imported just fine after switching to .Net Framework.

Answer (score 0):

When creating a new project for the Add in on visual, one should select the '**Class Library (.NET FRAMEWORK)**' and not the 'Class Library' option which tends automatically set a target framework for your .dll file.